# Changing default idle (&pip) in a python3 virtual env

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, python-venv

I have created a virtual environment for a python3 project.

```
phil@shuttle:$ python3 -m venv venv
phil@shuttle:$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) phil@shuttle:$ python -V
Python 3.5.3
(venv) phil@shuttle:$
```

However, when I am in it, idle still defaults to python 2.7. The idle3 command work fine.

Can I change the default version of idle within the virtual environment (and not outside of it) so that don't keep using the wrong version?

(Supplementary question: do I have to do similar for pip/pip3?)

[Running Ubuntu 17.04]

Comment: Edited for clarification, I am running Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDLE is run by python, not the reverse.  If you run

```
(venv) phil@shuttle:$ python -m idlelib
```

where python is 3.5.3, then that python will start the IDLE that comes with 3.5.3.

I do not have `idle` or `idle3` commands on Windows, so  I cannot answer questions about it.

To run pip inside the venv, replace `idlelib` with `pip` and add pip arguments.  If pip is not installed inside the venv, first run `python -m ensurepip` and then run pip to upgrade pip.

Comment: Thanks, I think that has worked for pip. Sorry, I don't know how to half accept an answer.

Comment: What happens when you try to start IDLE?

Comment: (venv) phil@shuttle:$ idle

launches a window for the Python 2.7.13 Shell (I want it to launch Python 3, which is what the venv is set for).

Comment: OK, so a bit more poking.
 
    (venv) phil@shuttle:$  python -m idlelib 

launches idle3, so putting 

    alias idle='python -m idlelib'

into .bashrc overrides the script in /usr/bin/idle and gives the behaviour I want.

Thanks Terry, wouldn't have got there without you.